# How to embed youtube playlist collection in an iframe

Tags: iframe, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I have a requirement where i have to display the youtube playlist collection from an url (in a html web page.).

for example the url (which has 2 playlists):

```
https://www.youtube.com/user/vikaskottari/playlists
```

When i use this url in an iframe, it displays a blank screen, with a console error:

```
Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/user/vikaskottari/playlists' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

any idea how do i achieve this.

Comment: were you solve it?

Answer (score -1):

use this script instead

https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID?playlist=aaaaaa,bbbbb,cccccc
where aaaaa, bbbbb,ccccc are the id of the youtube video.

or this one
https://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=playlist&list=yyyyyy

where yyyyyy is the id of youtube playlist
regards